# Run service on Remote Server using Nagios custome bash/shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, nagios, nagiosxi

I have to check service is running or not on Remote Server(192.168.1.105) using Nagios Server if service is not running then I want to run this service.

I am using **Nagios with NRPE**.

For this I am using below script

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "index.js" >/dev/null; then
echo "index.js is Running."
exit 0
else
echo "index.js is Stopped."
exit 2
fi
```

With help of above script i am able to check service is running or not.

But my question is that if service is not running so how can i run this service.

For run service on remote server i am just edit the above service as mentioned in below

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -f "index.js" >/dev/null; then
echo "index.js is Running."
exit 0
else
echo "index.js is Stopped."
servicestatus=$(ssh root@192.168.1.105 nohup node /root/demo/index.js > index.log &)
echo "$servicestatus"
exit 2
fi
```

But this is not working for me.

Comment: You are redirecting stdout to `index.log` so nothing will be in the variable `servicestatus`

Comment: @123 $(ssh root@192.168.1.105 nohup node /root/demo/index.js > index.log &) command not generating any pid of index.js

Comment: You are running it on a different server no?  Why would you expect the process to show up on the current server?

Comment: @123 yes I have to run "nohup node /root/demo/index.js > index.log &" command on 192.168.1.105 server from 192.168.1.103 server.